# HLS segments began to be created with a duration of 200 seconds

Tags: ffmpeg

An example of a startup that worked properly for a year.

```
-i pipe: -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f hls -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 1800 -hls_flags independent_segments
```

These parameters previously created segments in 6 seconds

But since August 2, the segments have become 200 seconds each and I can't find the reason why this happens.

Especially since this problem is relevant under Windows and Linux, as well as in a more recent version of ffmpeg.